# vuejs3 Data is not sent from the post list to the detail view page

Tags: vuejs3

I'm trying to try the post detail page in the post list. I tried to implement moving to the detail view by moving to the data of the corresponding value to detailpage (params.id) when clicking tr in the post list table, but I failed. What part is wrong? What I was thinking of was getting that content from an empty array like a post list page. But that seems to be the wrong idea.

list.vue

```
 <template>
  <tr v-for="params in form" :key="params" @click="detailPage(params.id)"">
        <td>{{params.title}}</td>
        <td>{{params.company}}</td>
        <td>{{params.company_url}}</td>
        <td>{{params.location}}</td>
        <td>{{params.description}}</td>
        <td>{{params.date_posted}}</td>
      </tr>
</template>
<script setup>
import axios from 'axios';
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router';
import { ref } from "vue";

const form = ref([]);
axios.get("api/jobs/all",{
  params: {
        title: "",
        company: "",
        company_url: "",
        location: "",
        description: "",
        date_posted: "",
  }
})
.then((res)=>{
  console.log(res.data)
  form.value = res.data;
})
const detailPage = id =>{
  router.push({
    name: 'BoardDetail',
    params:{
      id,
    }
  })
}
</script>
```

detail.vue

```
<template>
 <div class="line-height">
          <div class="display_f">
            <div>title</div>
            <p>{{form.title}}``</p>
          </div>
          <hr/>
          <div class="display_f">
            <div>company</div>
            <p> {{form.company}}</p>
          </div>
          <hr/>
          <div class="display_f">
            <div>url</div>
            <p> {{form.company_url}}</p>
          </div>
          <hr/>
          <div class="display_f">
            <div>location</div>
            <p>{{form.location}}</p>
          </div>
          <hr/>
          <div class="display_f">
            <div>content</div>
            <div class="write_widt"><p>{{form.description}}</p></div>
          </div>
          <hr/>
          <div class="display_f">
            <div>date</div>
            <p>{{form.date_posted}}</p>
          </div>
       </div>
</template>
<script setup>
import { ref } from "vue";
import axios from 'axios';

const form = ref([
        title: "",
        company: "",
        company_url: "",
        location: "",
        description: "",
        date_posted: "",
]);
axios.get("api/jobs/get/{id}")
.then((res)=>{
  console.log(res.data)
  form.value = res.data;
})
</script>
```

router.js

```
  {
    path: '/BoardDetail/{id}',
    name: 'BoardDetail',
    component: ToBoardDetail,
    props:true
  },
```

Comment: don't `.vue` files need `<template>` as the top level for the markup? - any errors or warnings in the console? by the way, you tagged both vue2 and vue3, yet your code is clearly not vue2

Comment: There is a template, but I haven't used it for code review

Comment: Ok, that's fine - what about errors or warnings, did you check for those?

Comment: 422 (Unprocessable Entity) Axios error.   Is the format of receiving the data wrong?

Comment: I thought the only difference between list and detail was id, so I used a similar format. Is there anything else?

Comment: any errors or warnings in the console

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 422 (Unprocessable Entity) << this console.error and axios error "Unprocessable Entity"

Comment: well, perhaps you should investigate that error - it's likely that `api/jobs/get/{id}` is the culprit since the backend won't know how to process an id with the exact value `"{id}"` - which is what you're requesting

Comment: oh, and your `form` ref in `detail.vue` is completely wrong ... it should be an object not an array

Comment: The backend address for practice is job/get/{id}, and the swagger data is id. Enter the id in swagger and the data will appear in the list.

Comment: Should I write ref({}) rather than ref([]) if it is an object and not an array?

Comment: you are fetching `api/jobs/get/{id}` ... what do you think replaces `{id}` with the id you want? `axios.get` doesn't know what you want, you have to put an id there instead of `{id}` ... have a look at the actual request that is actually sent by the browser - and yes, `{}` not `[]` - since that's what I said

Comment: I made the API address itself like this: /jobs/get/{id} is
The data condition is id: integer.

Comment: yes, you did ... seems you don't understand the problem, nothing in the code you've posted will replace `{id}` with the `id` you want to fetch data for .... what is the exact URL of request being made by the browser  (you can see that in the browser developer tools) is `{id}` being (magically) replaced by an actual id? or is the request made for `{id}`

Comment: this actual url is api/jobs/get/{id} , Interpretation is not smooth because I use a translator

Comment: then there's your issue ... you need to send an actual id, not {id}